# animated page scroll to anchor from top of page only

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I have an element that takes up the full height of the viewport when that page first loads. I would like to animate a scroll to the next element when the user swipes or scrolls down. Once at the second element, the scroll would work as normal. I want to have the page animate scroll back to the top of the page if the user swipes or scrolls back into the first div.

I have tried this but get weird results. Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
    var winHgt = $(window).innerHeight();
    var yPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var dir = detectDirection();
    console.log(winHgt);
    console.log(dir);
    console.log(dir);
    
    if(dir === "down"){
        if(yPos < winHgt){
            goToOne();
        }
    }
});
```